# migrating specific project in sonarqube 7.3

Tags: sonarqube, migration, sonarqube5.6, sonarqube7

We are planning to migrate from Sonarqube 5.6 version to Sonarqube 7.3 developer edition.

Because of huge lines of code we are planning to migrate specific project to Developer edition to regulate cost Hence Is there any way in to migrate only specific project not all the projects from current instance to Developer edition?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to do migrate a specific project: on startup of SonarQube the whole database is migrated in place. The commercial [Sonar DB Copy Tool](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+DB+Copy+Tool) is copying table by table and also not based on a project. That is why it is so very important to make a database backup before you start migrating for the case something goes wrong (no rollback mechanism available). To prevent the migration of some large projects you can remove them before you upgrade and start the migration. See also the [migration path](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) documentation. The migration path you have to follow is: 5.x => 5.6.7 LTS => 6.7.x LTS => 7.x. Starting with an empty database can also be a consideration.